# Названия рыб

Tags: этимология

Такие рыбы, как, например, карась, плотва, щука, карп, водятся практически в каждом русском пресном водоеме (если он, конечно, не окончательно отравлен стоками заводов). А вот названия всех этих рыб остаются непонятными. Я так предполагаю, что они относятся корнями к каким-то очень древним словам, ибо получили эти названия очень давно. Может, кто-то расскажет, что означают названия самых распространенных рыб российских водоемов.
И, кстати, отдельно интересует белый амур. Почему белый, понятно, а вот почему - амур? Речь о дальневосточной реке или божестве любви?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Многие названия рыб, встречающиеся на Северо-Западе России, имеют финно-угорские корни: сначала эти слова проникли в русские диалекты, затем были перенесены в Сибирь, на Дальний Восток и закрепились в русском литературном языке.

Так, из прибалтийско-финских языков заимствованы следующие названия рыб: килька (эстонское kilu), корюшка (вепсское koreh, карельское kuoreh), кумжа (карельское kumžu, в свою очередь, из саамского), ряпушка (эстонское rääbuskas), салака (финское silakka «салака», salakka «уклейка», ливское salak «корюшка»), сиг (эстонское, вепсское siig), хариус (карельское harjus).

Из саамского: камбала (kambel), мойва (majv «молодь рыбы»), навага (navaig), пикша (tehhssa), пинагор (pinna-garra), сайда (saide).

Названия морских рыб саамского происхождения были усвоены славянами на побережье Белого и Баренцева морей, а слова – сиг, хариус, ряпушка, корюшка – ещё в бассейне Балтийского моря.

Сорожка - от  сорога (оно проникло не только в Сибирь, но даже на Аральское море в форме сарожка), обозначающее плотву, хотя и родственно карельскому, вепсскому särg(i) «плотва», но по данным известного лингвиста А.С. Герда, восходит к хантыйскому, мансийскому sorroh (название определенного вида рыб). http://arhfish.ru/?p=7894

Лосось был известен индоевропейским народам с древнейших времен. Многие народы сохранили это слово: древнеиндийское laksa, немецкое Lachs, норвежское, датское, исландское laks, литовское lasisa - лосось, в тохарском языке, который затерялся в веках и в китайском Туркестане, это означало рыбу вообще. Это слово восходит корню «лак» - пятно, капля, что объясняется легко внешним видом рыбы. Можно добавить, что в северных говорах лосось называют пестряк, пестрянка.

Угорь. Это слово известно многим народам: литовское angis - уж, anguis - змея, латинское anguilla - угорь, anguis - змея. Эти все слова восходят к одному индоевропейскому корню оgrь  - змееподобный, змея.

Спорным остается происхождение слов судак, густера, карп.

В русском языке  слово «судак» впервые зафиксировано в 1547 г. в форме судочина, судокъ, в южных говорах русского языка - сула. чеш. candát, польск. sandacz, кашуб, sendacz, укр. судак, сандак, сандач. - иногда возводят к значению общего корня "песок" - водится в песке.

Название сазан заимствовано у тюркских народов. Этим самым именем обозначают Cyprinuscarpio, например, волжские татары, казахи, каракалпаки, узбеки, азербайджанцы. Тем же термином пользуются и русские на Волге, на Куре, в Средней Азии, на Амуре, также местами греки в Греции. Однако у южновеликорусов эта рыба носит название карп, карпия, короп, у поляков karp, у кашубов karp, karpie, у болгар крапъ.

Общеславянский характер имеют названия язь и елец. Их объединяет не только биологическое родство, но и общая праславянская форма азъ, язъ и ял, ел соответственно. Эти слова связаны праславянским язьпь - ясный, светлый, что соответствует окраске этих двух рыб.

Осётр - острый; латинское acipencer. От последнего научное название. Оно восходит к индоевропейскому корню «ек/ак» - острый, что вполне понятно, острые костные жучки покрывают тело рыбы.

Русское лещ - производное от звукоподражательного - лещати - плескаться. Можно сравнить с древнечешским dlesc, латышским leste.

Плотва - сербское название этой рыбы пловак, украинское сплотва явно указывает на связь со словами плыть и плот. Основа «плот» первоначально обозначало мальков всех без исключений рыб.

Собственно русскими слова по происхождению считают обычно те, которые возникли в XVI веке и позднее. Эти названия обычно прозрачны и не требуют дополнительных объяснений, во всяком случае, для рыбака: белуга - белая, клыкач - клыкастый, горбыль - горбатый, пузанок - пузатый, зубатка - зубатая, бычок напоминает тезку непропорционально большой головой. В этой группе названий можно встретить много словосложении типа красноперка, хвостокол. Особого названия заслуживает слово «бестер», название и саму рыбу получили путем скрещивания белуги и стерляди.

Comment: На мой взгляд, прекрасный ответ! Браво!

Comment: Язь,   у него рот косой, как бы в язвительной усмешке.
Лещ не плещется, рыба глубоководная, поверху не ходит. Иногда муть стаями со дна поднимает, пузыри идут, вот тогда бульканье, но и то на плеск не похоже.
Про ельца отдельно... В немецком это Weißfisch, белая рыба, Получается калька с пропуском буквы Б, ельца часто и путают с белорыбицей, очень похожи. Вариант в немецком и есть калька, белорыбица там у них не водится.
Сазан, Saza искажение русского саса, причастный или похожий. Очевидно так форму карася назвали, уж очень карась интересная рыба, спаривается со всеми карпообразными.

Comment: Ряпушка, одна из немногих рыб, изменяющих цвет, когда полежит немного, желтеет и пятнами идет, рябая становится.

Comment: и то-то елец в нидерландах --serpeling, серпом у нас инструмент зовут. см.http://fion.ru/images/forum/faa862b6ec153cedfc1d1519c4c41dd6.jpg

Comment: Но лещ очень даже плещется, когда его поймаешь. Видимо, от этого и название.  
Эх, ряпушка сиг... Какая рыба!!! ))))  
А интересно, карп и латинское carpus (плод) - не родственные?

Comment: Лещ на леске,  как кусок фанеры, отличить даже сложно. Одна из самых вялых рыб. Вообще-то все рыбы хвостом машут, а лучше всех плещется щука да окунь. Это по опыту. По утру на зорьке, щука самая шумная рыба. Трудновато с названием леща,  от плеск, скорее от лещить--хлопать. Вот хвостом широким  он и хлопает, лениво.
Созвучно словам лещина,  лещадь.

Comment: карп и есть плод, рыба разводится, в прудах.

Answer (score 2):

Окунь, да поплавок окунет моментально при хорошем клеве. Это раз, а потом, как конь  мечется...

Щука, сука,  Волк водяной. А ловят сук на на приманку.

Плотва, с берега хорошей плотвы не выловишь, на глубине плот нужен.
Еще название плотвы - сорога, по пути как сор ловится. Дряная рыба, плохо чистишь, горько есть.

Уклейка - одновременно и клюет бешено, и скользкая как не знамо что.

Лещ - бедняга, сплющенный как орех лещины. тут не понятно, что вперед.

Судак, судя по облику, окунь, но круче. Сударь.

Таймень - рыба тихая и мало ловится. Тайно и мало. Украдкой искать.
И так можно и еще. Рыб много, и все более или менее прозрачно с названиями.

Амур  два вида черный и белый.  Это как лещ и подлещик...
Вообще-то это амурская плотва, разновидность европейской, по имени реки и названа,
завезена в центр России. Отдельная история с названием реки, не от китаез.
На дальнем востоке, не знаю,  почему, все большое, наши сороки там в два раза больше.

Comment: вообще-то карп, не наше слово, из латыни. и сазан тоже. наше это карась, хотя тоже не наше.   у нас просто было бы ка, хорошая рыба и везде ловится, приставили приставку  рась, русская то бишь.приняли. и только здесь ее ловят, а на западе лишь разводят.
что интересно рыба коричневая  кара, можно сказать  а еще и царская. для царей и разводили.

Answer (score 0):

*Rutilus* — рыба, имеющая самое большое количество названий. Это плотва. Но почему её назвали плотвой? Я знаю точный ответ.
Это началось с тех пор, когда человек начал сплавлять лес по течениям рек. Сооружались плоты из кругляка. Они стояли вдоль берегов подолгу, дожидаясь сплава по течению. Из-под коры выползали короеды, гусеницы и прочий "корм" для рыбы. Тогда и была замечена рыба, вода от плеска которой кипела. Так и назвали её плотвой. Название стало обобщённым к этой рыбке (по причине широкого распространения сплава леса по всей Евразии в давние годы).